# Unable to form a Circular Image in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have used the following code in my view controller to display the image either from a camera or from the photo library in the circular form. But, I am not getting the desired result as there image is not filling up the entire circle. I have showed my code and the screenshot of the resulting image below. Appreciate your help! Thanks!

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        image1.makeRounded()
    }
}
```

---

```
//MARK:- Image Picker
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    //This is the tap gesture added on my UIImageView.
    @IBAction func didTapOnImageView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //call Alert function
        showAlert()
    }
    //Show alert to selected the media source type.
    private func showAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Selection", message: "From where you want to pick this image?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.getImage(fromSourceType: .camera)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Album", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.getImage(fromSourceType: .photoLibrary)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    //get image from source type
    private func getImage(fromSourceType sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
        //Check is source type available
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) {
            let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePickerController.delegate = self
            imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
            present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    //MARK:- UIImagePickerViewDelegate.
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
            guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
            //Setting image to your image view
            self?.image1.image = image
        }
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension UIImageView {
    func makeRounded() {
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because your image is not square

You need to change your imageView content mode to aspect fill in the xib or storyboard

[image]

or you can do it by code too

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIImageView {

    func makeRounded() {
    
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
      }
  }
```